# OCaml function type ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b

Tags: ocaml

I'm having some problems understanding how a function of this type works.

```
let try_it f x = f x;;
val try_it : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
```

The above function, try_it accepts a function f which accepts a polymorphic parameter and returns a polymorphic type. Now I can easily pass functions + parameters to try_it of varying number of parameters like below and it works.

```
let add_three a b c = a + b + c;;

let add_two a b = a + b;;

let try_it f x = f x;;

print_endline(string_of_int(try_it add_two 23 45));;
print_endline(string_of_int(try_it add_three 23 4 56));;
```

Now if the above works, why can't I create a function called try_it2 which is defined like below and pass it the same functions and parameters but in reverse order?

```
let try_it2 x f = f x;;
val tryit2 : 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

To me try_it2 is the same as try_it with only the parameters order changed but I'm obviously missing something here. Can someone
please put me on the correct path?

Comment: I tried `let try_it2 x f = f x;;` and it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is that the number of arguments of your try_it function is fixed.

You must understand correctly what goes on on this line:

```
print_endline(string_of_int(try_it add_two 23 45));;
```

try_it add_two 23 returns a function of type int -> int, which is in turn evaluated over the value 45, giving 23 + 45.

but if you change the definition of try_it as you did, then this line becomes:

```
print_endline(string_of_int(try_it 23 add_two 45));;
```

So that try_it 23 add_two returns a (int -> int) function, evaluated over 45.

Have a nice day !

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines for the try_it function in my posted example but I couldn't figure out why the second example won't work. Your explanation really exposed another feature of this deep language that I kind of grossed over. Thank-you.